# How to show line number in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here I am trying to build an edit text in which shows the line number whenever new line encounters. I made my own Custom edit text as described in this [Using this Link.](https://gist.github.com/lifeparticle/de9224424d14a9d6e185) 
Here's my code

```
public class MyEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {

    private Rect rect;
    private Paint paint;

    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        rect = new Rect();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(20);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int baseline = getBaseline();
        for (int i = 0; i < getLineCount(); i++) {
            canvas.drawText("" + (i+1), rect.left, baseline, paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight();
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Here's XML layout of MainActvity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Type here"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/editor_area"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And Here's the Main Activity Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
    TextView textView;
    MyEditText myEditText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myEditText = (MyEditText) findViewById(R.id.editor_area);

             // Now what should be further steps to achieve the task
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out what's should I do next in this to do this line number thing. I saw many answers on stackoverflow but didn't solve the query, I am new to android. Please help.

Thanks

**EDIT** : After doing the alterations based on the following answers this is what i am getting in logcat Window

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aman.demo/com.example.aman.demo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.example.aman.demo.MyEditText
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.example.aman.demo.MyEditText
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.example.aman.demo.MyEditText
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
                                                       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2320)
                                                       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1725)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:615)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                       at com.example.aman.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: I am not able to show line numbers in edit text whenever a new line hits.

Comment: Look at the layout XML on the example you're following. Do they have an `<AppCompatEditText>` there?

Comment: Right, also replace         <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText by <your.package.declaration.MyEditText

Comment: yes, In XML layout I have specified the AppCompatEditText.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking. What do they show in the layout in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this on your xml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
```

To this:

```
<your.package.MyEditText
```

Also add this parameters into your editext

```
 <your.package.MyEditText 
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
     <!-- Multiline input -->
     android:lines="8"
     <!-- Total Lines prior display --> 
     android:minLines="6"
     <!-- Minimum lines --> 
    android:gravity="top|left" 
    <!-- Cursor Position -->
     android:maxLines="10" 
    <!-- Maximum Lines --> 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    <!-- Height determined by content --> 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     <!-- Fill entire width --> 
     android:scrollbars="vertical" 
    <!-- Vertical Scroll Bar --> />
```

Your crash is because you need the constructor from xml file, add this :

```
public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
    init();
}

public MyEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init(){

    rect = new Rect();
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(20);
}
```

Comment: Did that , but what should i write in main Activity class to display the line numbers?

Comment: Nothing, you just need to write text on your UI, press enter to break lines

Comment: Thank you diegovelper, but still, app is crashing.

Comment: Crashing? Put the logcat

Comment: @Logan check my solution

Comment: hey diegoveloper ,i just post the logcat window, please check it out.

Comment: Thanks diegoveloper , but the text is drawing over the numbers.

Comment: add a paddingLeft

Comment: add a paddingLeft? where

Comment: <your.package.MyEditText 
    android:paddingLeft ="20dp"

Comment: you mean to increase the padding of EditText?

Comment: Yeah i will for sure , but that paddingleft thing didn't work

Answer (score 2):

custom EditText xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="com.wade.webview.HtmlEditActivity">
    <com.wade.webview.LineNumberEditText
        android:id="@+id/lineNumberEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ***android:paddingLeft="100px"***
        android:gravity="top|left"
        ***android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"***
        android:text=""
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />
</ScrollView>
```

Custom EditText java
    package com.wade.webview;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class LineNumberEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {
    private Rect rect;
    private Paint paint;
    final LineNumberEditText me;

    public LineNumberEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        me = this;
        rect = new Rect();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setTextSize(40);
        **setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());**
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int baseline = getBaseline();
        for (int i = 0; i < getLineCount(); i++) {
            canvas.drawText(String.format("%04d:", (i+1)), rect.left, baseline, paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight();
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer to https://www.github.com/wade-fs/wade_webview

Comment: Upvoted because of this: `String.format("%04d:", (i+1)`

Answer (score 0):

In your layout XML, you not using the subclassed EditText you made, you need to declare it by replacing android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText by your.package.declaration.MyEditText

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <your.package.declaration.MyEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Type here"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/editor_area"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want the "Type Here" to not be part of the text replace android:text by android:hint

Also, your MyEditText miss the constructor (Context, AttributeSet) that is necessary for inflation by XML, so add it to the class:

```
public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    rect = new Rect();
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(20);
}
```

And one last note, call super.onDraw before drawing the numbers yourself.

The super implementation may draw the white background, erasing you numbers

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int baseline = getBaseline();
    for (int i = 0; i < getLineCount(); i++) {
        canvas.drawText("" + (i+1), rect.left, baseline, paint);
        baseline += getLineHeight();
    }
}
```

The result is:
[image: Working]

Unfortunately the drawing is join with the text, I would say to increase text paddiing but did not worked.

Comment: Ok but what should be the changes in main Activity code to display the line numbers

Comment: None, since the Component will draw the lines by itself, you just missed to add it to the screen and the constructor. If this question helped you please upvote, if it solved your problem please accept it as correct.

Comment: Hey Marcos ,  I have changed all the things as you have mentioned but problem is still same, what should i write int main Activity class to run onDraw method mentioned in MyEditTextClass?

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myEditText = (MyEditText) findViewById(R.id.editor_area);

             // Now what should be further steps to achieve the task
 }

Comment: Nothing is needed, the class would be able to draw by itself, i gonna make a test here also

Comment: The App is crashing.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aman.demo/com.example.aman.demo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.example.Myname.demo.MyEditText

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.example.Myname.demo.MyEditText
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.example.Myname.demo.MyEditText
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]

Comment: I copied your code with my alterations and it did worked

Comment: I told you, you need a constructor with (Context, AttributeSet) check the answer there

Comment: Just add the parameter

Comment: Hey marcos , thanks but i am still confused why the text is over the numbers, Can you help me out of it?

Comment: I tried a solution, going to think about it, and remember to upvote this ;)

Comment: The padding didn't work because you're calling through to the `super` constructor that takes only a `Context`. The XML attribute values are in the `AttributeSet`, and you're losing the values 'cause you're not passing that up.

Comment: Well noticed @MikeM. thanks, Logan, theres your solution

Comment: Just add super(context, attrs) together