# Xamarin Forms Editor Scrollbar

Tags: android, xamarin, canvas, scroll, editor

I have a need for an Editor, with a checkbox in a left margin for each line.

(When the user clicks on the check box, the text for that line changes color.)

At the moment I can create the check boxes dynamically in a grid when newlines are added to the editor.

However once the editor scrolls, I have no way to sync the scrolling for the check box grid as I don't have access to the behavior or events of the editor scrollbar.

Two questions:

- Any way I can access that scrollbar?
- Any way I can change the font color upon a check box click

**UPDATE:**

I've decided to draw the checkboxes on the editor renderer's OnDraw instead, as per this:
[How to show line number in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579338/how-to-show-line-number-in-edittext)

Then I will handle Touch events on the editor to turn the checks on and off. However my problem now is that the checkboxes drawn on the canvas don't scroll with the editor's text, so I'm stuck again.

Any ideas?

Comment: To get the scrolled events, you'll probably need a behavior or renderer to hook into. Regarding the color change, I don't know if it's possible to change the text color of individual lines in an editor

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I found some methods in the renderer to try:

int range = ComputeVerticalScrollRange();
int extent = ComputeVerticalScrollExtent();

However both return visible height of the control, rather than the max scrollable height. 

Any idea of how I might access the max scrollable height?

Comment: Could you provide the code you have tried for us?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Wendy, added updates above.

Comment: Could you provide your code not a link?  I am not sure what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again Wendy. I've worked it out. Please see posted answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

Below is the solution I had with the drawn text not scrolling.

My mistaken assumption was that text drawn 'offscreen' would automatically scroll into view with scrolling actions.

It appears however that the drawing is done only in relation to the visible size of the editor, not the virtual size.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int baseline = getBaseline();
    for (int i = 0; i < getLineCount(); i++) {

        //problem line
        //canvas.drawText("" + (i+1), rect.left, baseline, paint);

        //PROBLEM RESOLVED WITH
        canvas.drawText("" + (i+1), rect.left, baseline - ScrollY, paint);

        baseline += getLineHeight();
    }
}
```